# Getting groups and permission right for apache uploads

Tags: linux, permissions

I did have all this working for a long time but something had got messed up I am going round in circles.

So I allow uploads to a site. Before the file is uploaded a folder is created using mkdir in PHP. Then the file gets sent using ssh2 in PHP. Don't ask why that's just the way it is right now and is too problematic to change at the moment.

So for ssh2 to upload the file I am having to set the ssh2 users group as the owner of the new directory. But when I use mkdir to create the folder that is setting apache as the group owner of the folder so the file wont upload.

Even when I set the ssh2 user to be the owner of the parent directory the new folder from PHP has apache as the owner.

So what I need is the ssh2 user to always be the owner of folders created in that directory even if I use mkdir.

Or allow the ssh2 user to upload to the folder created using mkdir, I have tried using acl for this but it's not making a difference:

```
setfacl -R -m u:ssh2user :rw /home/uploads
```

The mkdir folder are being set with 775 permission so really I should be able to add the ssh2 user to a group and make sure new folders created are done with that group I tried that with chmod g+s / and still the new mkdir folder is group owned by apache.

So I keep getting stuck with either being able to make folders with mkdir or add files with ssh2 but not both!

EDIT:

So I have used chmod -R g+s /home/uploads and this has set the group of new folders how I want them, but ssh2 is still not being allowed to move files there despite being in the group the directory is owned by.

Comment: If you're making a folder permissions rw, then `setfacl -R -m u:ssh2user :rw /home/uploads` wont cut it as you need the 'x' perm. Use `setfacl -R -m u:ssh2user:rwx /home/uploads` instead

Comment: That is only working if I apply it to folders that are already created, if I create a new folder with mkdir the acl is not applying to it, this I think is where the problem is.

Comment: I've decided just to drop mkdir and use all ssh2, it's easier to work out!